# Php associative array value update from a form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I am trying to update value of an associative array from form data. When the user presses submit, the array values should be updated. Here is the code below.

```
$userInfo = array('new_user_name' => '',
                  'new_user_email'=>'',
                  'new_user_mobile'=>'',
                  'new_user_area'=>'',
                  'new_user_address'=>'');



if (isset($_POST['submit-add-user'])) {

    foreach($userInfo as $key => $value){
   $key['new_user_name'] = $_POST['name'] ;
   $key['new_user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
   $key['new_user_mobile'] = $_POST['mobile'];
   $key['new_user_area'] = $_POST['area'];
   $key['new_user_address'] = $_POST['address'];
    }
   
   
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please don't use all caps, it's difficult to read and it might be interpreted as the equivalent of shouting.

Comment: Caps and bold letters can also be used to bring attention to an important word in English as well.  Use caps sparingly.  Here's an example.  Please change your English from UPPERCASE to lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you refine your question.

Use the same keys, with different array names.

This would just assign a subset of posted form values to a new array if given:

```
<?php

$form_fields = ['name', 'email', 'mobile', 'area', 'address'];

$dirty = [];
foreach($form_fields as $name) {
    $dirty[$name] = $_POST[$name] ?? null;
}
```

If you want to compare changes in simple arrays:

```
$before = [
    'name'  => 'Peggy',
    'email' => 'peggy@example.com'
];

$after = [
    'name'  => 'Peter',
    'email' => 'peggy@example.com'
];

var_export(array_diff_assoc($after, $before));
```

Output:

```
array ( 'name' => 'Peter', )
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure if you are aware, but when you load code in pretty much any language it starts at the top and initializes all your variables. It reads your code top to bottom. This includes your array so this would not be possible, seeing as though its reinitialized every page load.

Try looking into databases and their application for your problem. You can submit form data using `pdo` for example.

Comment: The all-caps in your answer appear to have been in response to the OP's use of all-caps. While I personally found that amusing, this kind of behavior can be perceived as rude, and is not really behavior we want to encourage. In the future, simply edit the OP's question to change all uses of upper-case to lower-case. Thanks.